# Excel VBA to Remove Columns Based on Multiple Headers on Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Would the below code be able to be modified to 1 loop through all sheets in a workbook and 2 remove multiple columns based on their headers?

example: "status","Status Name","Status Processes" etc.)?
And then cycle through all sheets in the wkbk to do the same checks?

```
Sub remove_columns()
    For i = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Cells(1, i), "Status") Then Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, basically you wrap your current loop in another loop of sheets. Also amend your If statement or try a Select Case formulation which looks neater.

Comment: will that work if I dont know the sheet names? I will go look up what a select case is, sorry im new to VBA. ty for the quick response.

Comment: Yes, just google 'loop through sheets' or similar and you will find many examples. Try something yourself and then post back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dim a as long, w as long, vDELCOLs as variant, vCOLNDX as variant
vdelcols = array("status","Status Name","Status Processes")
with thisworkbook
    for w=1 to .worksheets.count
        with worksheets(w)
            for a=lbound(vdelcols) to ubound(vdelcols)
                vcolndx=application.match(vdelcols(a), .rows(1), 0)
                if not iserror(vcolndx) then
                    .columns(vcolndx).entirecolumn.delete
                end if
            next a
        end with
    next w
end with
```

You obviously have less columns to delete than columns that exist. Look for matches to the columns to delete rather than comparing every column to the delete list.

This looks (case-insensitive) for the column names in row 1.

Comment: This worked perfectly! ty, out of curiosity will this work the same if I replace all deletes with hidden's? ty again!

Comment: I don't see any reason why changing `.delete` to `.hidden = true` would not work.

Comment: Thanks! 1 final thought if you would be so kind, If I wanted to delete a row based on a column name and a value in that column would I be able to do that in this same code by adding in another array somehow? (in case it is multiple values in the column)  ty yet again!

Comment: Sure. After finding a non-error column number, use a similar routine to find a non-error row number in that column.

Comment: ty! im still very green to this, so I will try and figure out what that would look like, but at least in theory that can be done which is great news! thanks again.

Comment: Hello, I tried a few things but cant get it to work it kept just hiding the column but not the row/column combination

Comment: This is probably the time to take your modified code and post a new question using the code and detailing what you are attempting (examples help) and what doesn't happen the way you are expecting it to.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go like follows

```
Sub Main()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim i as Long

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With sh.UsedRange
            For i = .columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                If InStr(1, LCase(.columns(i).cells(1)), "status") Then .columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
            Next
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly reference the sheet, easy using `With` and you can use `LCase()` to avoid case sensitivity :

```
Sub remove_columns()
    Dim wS As WorkSheet
    For Each wS in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wS
            For i = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                If InStr(1, LCase(.Cells(1, i)), LCase("Status")) Then _
                    .Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
            Next i
        End With 'wS
    Next wS
End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW, the `.Sheets` container may contain charts, macro sheets, etc. for both `.Count` and reference (e.g. `For Each wS in ThisWorkbook.Sheets`).  The `Worksheets` container contains only worksheets.

Comment: @Jeeped : Thx for pointing it out, I knew but as I always use `Sheets` (and never use any Chart's sheets, and haven't the faintest clue of what you mean by *macro sheets* ^^), I never think of this! ;) I'll edit my answer to reflect that good point that may indeed avoid getting errors on non-worksheets! ;)